# Check whether item is the last in OnItemDataBind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, telerik, radgrid

Using Telerik RadGrid I'm binding a datasource and attach a method to the `OnItemDataBound` event.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="myGrid" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="myDataSource"
    OnItemDataBound="myMethod"
    >
```

I've been trying to find the solution for a while now with no luck. How could I check with the  item being bound is the last item to be bound. For example, the below method will be called for each record

```
protected void myMethod(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    //some condition to check whether the current item is the last
}
```

I hope if explained my problem clearly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and looked around but coudnt find any clean way of doing it, so had to rethink the approach and followed another approach. If you tell why you want the we can come up with diff approach

Comment: At the moment it's only to minipulate the look and feel. I know this could be done with javascript but I want to keep in on the server as there is already some similar code for other rows in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    if (e.Item.DataSetIndex == e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataSourceCount - 1)
    {
        //Last Grid Item 
    }
}
```

If paging, to check the last item on the page:

```
(e.Item.ItemIndex == e.Item.OwnerTableView.PageSize - 1)
```